# MVC Dynamic View Data and Dynamic Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, view, viewmodel

Traditionally, I have built MVC applications using view models with Data Annotations attributes, and I dynamically render the views using editor templates.  Everything works great, and it really cuts down on the time it takes me to build new views.  My requirements have recently changed.  Now, I can't define the view model at design time.  The properties that will be rendered on the view are decided at run time based on business rules.  Also, the validation rules for those properties may be decided at run time as well.  (A field that is not required in my domain model, may be required in my view based on business rules).  Also, the set of properties that will be rendered is not known until run time - User A may edit 6 properties from the model, while user B may edit 9 properties.

I am wondering if it is possible to create a model metadata provider that will supply my own metadata from business rules for an untyped view model like a collection of property names and values.  Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Are you using MVC's editor templates, then?

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to use MVC editor templates with loosely structured view data (like using the ViewData property).  The problem is that the loosely structured data does not integrate with the modelmetadata provider and so editor templates don't buy me much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by creating a more complex model, and using a custom editor template to make the model be rendered to look like a typical editor, but using the dynamic field information:

```
public class SingleRowFieldAnswerForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The fields answers to display.
    /// This is a collection because we ask the MVC to bind parameters to it,
    /// and it could cause issues if the underlying objects were being recreated
    /// each time it got iterated over.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<IFieldAnswerModel> FieldAnswers { get; set; } 
}

public interface IFieldAnswerModel
{
    int FieldId { get; set; }

    string FieldTitle { get; set; }

    bool DisplayAsInput { get; }

    bool IsRequired { get; }

    bool HideSurroundingHtml { get; }
}

// sample implementation of IFieldAnswerModel
public class TextAreaFieldAnswer : FieldAnswerModelBase<TextAreaDisplayerOptions>
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplates/SingleRowFieldAnswerForm.cshtml:

```
@helper DisplayerOrEditor(IFieldAnswerModel answer)
{
    var templateName = "FieldAnswers/" + answer.GetType().Name;
    var htmlFieldName = string.Format("Answers[{0}]", answer.FieldId);

    if (answer.DisplayAsInput)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => answer, templateName, htmlFieldName)
        // This will display validation messages that apply to the entire answer. 
        // This typically means that the input got past client-side validation and
        // was caught on the server instead.
        // Each answer's view must also produce a validation message for
        // its individual properties if you want client-side validation to be
        // enabled.
        @Html.ValidationMessage(htmlFieldName)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => answer, templateName, htmlFieldName)
    }
}
<div class="form-section">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var answer in Model.FieldAnswers)
                {
                    if (answer.HideSurroundingHtml)
                    {
                        @DisplayerOrEditor(answer)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var labelClass = answer.IsRequired ? "form-label required" : "form-label";
                        <tr>
                            <td class="@labelClass">
                                @answer.FieldTitle:
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-field">
                                <div>
                                    @DisplayerOrEditor(answer)
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So I populate my `SingleRowFieldAnswerForm` with a series of answer models. Each answer model type has its own editor template, allowing me to customize how different types of dynamic "properties" should be displayed. For example:

```
// EditorTemplates/FieldAnswers/TextAreaFieldAnswer.cshtml

@model TextAreaFieldAnswer

@{
    var htmlAttributes = Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("Answer", ViewData.ModelMetadata);
    // add custom classes that you want to apply to your inputs.
    htmlAttributes.Add("class", "multi-line input-field");
}
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Answer, Model.Options.Rows, 0, htmlAttributes)
@Html.ValidationMessage("Answer")
```

The next tricky part is that when you send this information to the server, it doesn't inherently know which type of `IFieldAnswerModel` to construct, so you can't just bind the `SingleRowAnswerForm` in your arguments list. Instead, you have to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveForm(int formId)
{
    SingleRowAnswerForm form = GetForm(formId);
    foreach (var fieldAnswerModel in form.FieldAnswers.Where(a => a.DisplayAsInput))
    {
        // Updating this as a dynamic makes sure all the properties are bound regardless
        // of the runtime type (since UpdateModel relies on the generic type normally).
        this.TryUpdateModel((dynamic) fieldAnswerModel, 
            string.Format("Answers[{1}]", fieldAnswerModel.FieldId));
        }
    ...
```

Since you provided MVC with each dynamic "property" value to bind to, it can bind each of the properties on each answer type without any difficulty.

Obviously I've omitted a lot of details, like how to produce the answer models in the first place, but hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice approach.  I was hoping to be able to leverage the model metadata infrastructure.  You have similar metadata in your IFieldAnswerModel that you would find in model metadata like HideSurroundingHtml and IsRequired (Model Metadata has quite a few).  The advantage to using modelmetadata is that you can rely on the built in editor templates to do some work automatically for you - for instance, if the property being rendered has modelmetadata.EditFormatString specified, the MVC template engine will automatically apply that format string without you writing code.

Comment: @MattMangold: That's true. In my case, I need to be able to provide specific configuration for each of these answer fields, and highly customize the display for each, so I had to follow this pattern. If you really just need to have a standard template for various dynamic properties, it's possible that you could get away with a custom ModelMetadataProvider coupled with a custom ModelBinder.

Comment: When I experimented with creating a custom ModelMetadataProvider, I had a hard time.  I created my own provider, but in the overrides, I could not actually figure out which property in my model was requesting metadata which I attributed to the fact that my view model is a collection of simple data types rather than a strongly typed view model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use The ViewData Property in your ViewModel, View and Controller, it is dynamic, so it can be resolved at runtime.

Comment: I still want to dynamically render my views using editor templates.  I am looking for a way to be able to do that using a loosely typed structure like ViewData