# Injecting Partial View Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am developing UI for a dynamic platform, a user can add his/her own properties to classes in platform. I will go through an example to make my question clear:

Say we have a class X with ID and DisplayName properties. These are default initial properties of class X. In the ASP.Net web Application I have created an associated form for class X with both properties bound to model. Yet users can add fields to this class and I want to create associated sections in the UI, but with condition that the user can offer correct HTML (or aspx) markup for new field(s) and the markup would render in the UI. This is to avoid changing code for little domain manipulations and does not require code recompile and server restart.

Said Otherwise, I want a functionality like saving partial views in the DB and loading them in the UI.

I have found [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353965/load-partial-views-from-database) so close to mine, yet the provided answer is not good enough.

If you can point me to any project, tutorial or sample code, I will appreciate it.

What I have done so far: I have checked Naked Objects for MVC, yet I think it is an overkill for my question. [MVC Form Factory](http://formfactory.apphb.com/) is very interesting but I need those added variables be accessible using provided template.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837948/mvc-dynamic-view-data-and-dynamic-views

Comment: @J-D.Thanks, it was very useful. Please provide it as an answer to mark it